# How to get accurate route for map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-directions-api

I'm trying to build a route using Google Directions API. It returns an array of waypoints, however, the number of waypoints is not enough to build a smoothed route, and as the result I receive quite inaccurate route what is super crucial and inappropriate for transport application. I also tried HERE maps, almost the same result.

Is there any other services that may build more accurate route, or any solution applicable to the Google Directions API?

Here is the function:

```
public func getWaypoints(startLocation: [Double]!, endLocation: [Double]!, mode:String? = "walking", lang:String? = "en") -> [Dictionary<String,Any>] {

    var resultedArray:[Dictionary<String,Any>] = []
    let routeGM = Just.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?", params: ["origin":"\(startLocation[0]),\(startLocation[1])", "destination": "\(endLocation[0]),\(endLocation[1])", "mode": mode!, "key":self.KEY, "language": lang!])

    if let _ = routeGM.error {
    } else {
        do {
            if let data = jsonToNSData(routeGM.json! as AnyObject), let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                let status = jsonData["status"] as! String
                if(status == "OK") {
                    let results = jsonData["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
                    let legs = results[0]["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

                    let steps = legs[0]["steps"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

                    for i in 0...steps.count-1 {
                        let item = steps[i]
                        let start = item["start_location"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                        let end = item["end_location"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                        resultedArray.append(["start_location_lat": start["lat"]!,"start_location_lng": start["lng"]!,"end_location_lat": end["lat"]!,"end_location_lng": end["lng"]!])
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("not found")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return resultedArray
}
```

Calling function:

```
func buildRoute(startCoord:[Double]!, endCoord:[Double]!) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let route:[Dictionary<String,Any>] = self.GMSRequest.getWaypoints(startLocation: startCoord,endLocation: endCoord, mode: "driving")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let path = GMSMutablePath()
            for item in route {
                path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item["start_location_lat"]! as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: item["start_location_lng"]! as! CLLocationDegrees))
                path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item["end_location_lat"]! as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: item["end_location_lng"]! as! CLLocationDegrees))
            }
            // Create the polyline, and assign it to the map.
            self.polyline.path = path
            self.polyline.strokeColor = Styles.colorWithHexString("#3768CD")
            self.polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
            self.polyline.geodesic = true
            self.polyline.map = self.mapView
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Route built based on waypoints]
[image: Route built based on waypoints]

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: @ReinierMelian ok, added

Comment: You need to pass as Mode @"driving" you are passing it?,can you post the code where you are calling this method?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have several scenario, where I pass walking mode and driving mode. In any case, I receive inaccurate path due to small number of waypoints. Code added.

Comment: I think i know what is your problem i will add an answer now, and you are right the Mode @"driving" is not the issue problem

Comment: Any luck? I have the same issue.